# advice for static template class

Tags: c++, templates, static, histogram, static-polymorphism

I have this problem (histogramming). I've a real space: `[a,b]` partitioned in some way (`[a0=a, a1, a2, ..., b]`). The partitioning may be with equal space (`a1 - a0 = a2 - a1 = ...`) or variables.

I need a class that handle this, with some methods to say given a value in which bin of the partition it belongs; other methods to find the center of a particular bin and more.

During the program I don't like to instantiate a class only to call these simple function like

```
Binner binner(binning);
binner.get_bin(1.3);
binner.get_centerbin(2);
```

so I tried to write a static class using template to do something like that:

```
Binner<binning>::get_bin(1.3);
Binner<binning>::get_centerbin(2);
```

is it a good idea? There are other way to do it? Now I've free functions like

```
double get_bin(double bin, Binning binning); // a lot of if/else inside
```

but I think it's too error prone.

Here my implementation:

```
enum Binning {CELL, LARGE, BE};
const double binning_LARGE[] = {0, 1.2, 1.425, 1.550, 1.800, 2.5};
const double binning_BE[] =  {0, 1.425, 1.550, 2.5};

template<Binning binning>
class Binner
{
public:
    static const double* bins;
    static const int n;
    static int get_bin(double value);
};

template<> const double* myclass<LARGE>::bins = binning_LARGE;
template<> const double* myclass<BE>::bins = binning_BE;

template<> const int myclass<LARGE>::n = sizeof(binning_LARGE) / sizeof(double);
template<> const int myclass<BE>::n = sizeof(binning_BE) / sizeof(double);

template<Binning binning> int myclass<binning>::get_bin(double value)
{
    return find_if(bins, bins + n,
           bind2nd(greater<double>(), value)) - bins - 1;
}

template<> int myclass<CELL>::get_bin(double value)
{
    return static_cast<int>(value / 0.025);
}
```

1. is it a good implementation / design?
2. Is there a way to avoid the `n` field using `std::vector`? How?
3. Is there a way to parametrize the `0.025`? I know that `double` can't be template parameter but can I write something similar to this:

   ```
   Binner<0.025> binner;
   ```
4. other / advices?

### Edit:

For the third point Why I can't do that:

```
template<Binning binning, int N=100>
class Binner
{
public:
    static const double* bins;
    static const int n;
    static int bin(double value);
};

...

template<Binning binning, int N> int Binner<CELL, N>::bin(double value)
{
    return static_cast<int>(value / (2.5 / N));
}
```

Comment: +1, I did not know that `double` cannot be `template` parameter.

Comment: looks like a good demonstration of usage of template. but i get a feeling that all you are doing can be achieved by choosing a proper STL container and defining the required methods.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, your design is ok, if you do not want to instantiate a class. Indeed, it seems a kind of [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) to me. Whether this makes sense depends on how you are planning to reuse this template.

Using a std::vector would allow you to get rid of the variable to hold the array size, for sure. Now, if this is good for your design, I don't know... it would move some complexity out of your template definition, to the binning definition (which now you can initialize very simply)...

Finally, you can instantiate your template passing a constant to it:

```
template < Binning binning, unsigned long N, unsigned long M>
class ... {
     <using N>
}
```

Comment: +1, I too find this design ok. But not confident enough to say it.

Comment: what is `N`? Is it `N = 2.5 / 0.025` (in my case) ?

Comment: I thought of it as the constant you would like to get rid of; it should be a long, say 25, so either you divide it 1000, or you define 2 such long constants in your template declaration...

Comment: I can't redeclare my template class with a different template argument. Now it is `Binning` and I need it. A solution could be to use negative enum values for variable size binning and positive for equal space binning.

Comment: What about: `template <Binning binning, unsigned long N, unsigned long M>`?

Comment: @sergio: sorry, I can't understand, can you expand your answer?

Answer (score 2):

have you considered a traits class?  Typically if you have static information that you want to separate from the behaviour in a class, you might consider creating a traits class that encapsulates that.

So I'd start with the default behaviour:

```
enum Binning {CELL, LARGE, BE};

template <Binning binning>
struct BinTraits
{
    // default behaviour
    int get_bin(double value) { return value / 0.025; } 
};
```

Then I'd provide the specialisations:

```
const double binning_LARGE[] = {0, 1.2, 1.425, 1.550, 1.800, 2.5};
const double binning_BE[] =  {0, 1.425, 1.550, 2.5};

template <typename RandomAccessCollectionT>
int get_bin_impl(double value, RandomAccessCollectionT collection, unsigned size)
{
    return find_if(collection, collection + size,
           bind2nd(greater<double>(), value)) - collection - 1;
}

template <>
struct BinTraits<LARGE>
{
    int get_bin(double value) { return get_bin_impl(value, binning_LARGE, sizeof(binning_LARGE) / sizeof(binning_LARGE[0])); } 
};

template <>
struct BinTraits<BE>
{
    int get_bin(double value) { return get_bin_impl(value, binning_BE, sizeof(binning_BE) / sizeof(binning_BE[0])); } 
};
```

Then I'd put the actual container behaviour in another class that requires binning behaviour (lets call it `HashTable`):

```
template <typename BinTraits>
class HashTable
{
public:
    void insert(double value)
    {
        int bin = BinTraits::get_bin(value);
        _bins[bin].insert(value);
    }
    // _bin is a multimap or something
};
```

Comment: Your solution is good but I agree with Jaywalker: we're over-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the usage of `find_if` and `bind2nd` as well as functors, it seems as if you are quite knowledgeable about STL and some advanced C++ concepts; yet, what you are trying to do seems to be over-engineering. While I can't fully understand what you are trying to do but it seems that you could do away with templates completely and use just a class (instantiated with different values) and method parameters.